# How to check Date instance init success or not in Kotlin?

Tags: spring-boot, date, kotlin, initialization, unix-timestamp

I am coding a function to check if an Integer `x` is UNIX timestamp format or not. Current I'm think the solution is **check if the program can initialize an Date instance from `x` or not**. But I can't found how to check it in Kotlin. Please help me with it.

Note: The enviroment I use:

- SpringBoot 2.5
- Kotlin 1.3.5

Udate 1:
I came up with a way using try catch but I guess my approach to the "UNIX timestamp" problem is wrong. Seem like with every Integer a new Date can be created in below code.

```
val x: Long = 123456;
try {
    val a = Date(x)
} catch (e : Exception) {
    throw DataInvalidException("x must be UNIX timestamp")
}
```

Comment: Actually, UNIX timestamp is not a date format, but the amount of seconds passed since 1970-01-01. So, yes, any `UInt` will be a valid timestamp.

Comment: By the usual definition a Unix timestamp is in seconds, whereas the constructor of the old-fashioned `Date` class accepts milliseoncds. Did you intend one of the units, and if so, which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Unix timestamp is just the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00Z.  So *any* number is a valid Unix timestamp (including 123456, which if I've calculated correctly is just 1970-01-02 10:17:36Z).

If you want to put any restrictions on the range of dates and/or times that you will accept, then that can of course be done; but you'd have to understand that you'd be ruling out genuine timestamps.